# ggpaired boxplot - configuring axis title size, background etc

Tags: r, ggplot2, boxplot

I used ggpaired to create two grouped boxplots which I could now put together in one plot/grafic and save as jpg. so far so good - but I didn't figure out how I can arrange the size of the axis titles, the labels of x-axis, etc - I'm not sure if there is such a possibility?

Besides that, after I put the two boxplots together, the background is now gray. In the single boxplots the background is the ggtheme = theme_minimal. Any idea how to fix this?

Here is an illustration

[my saved version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zvLg4.png),

[the version with the background i want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O4cKT.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can change the theme of a `ggplot` object. Several complete themes are provided in the `ggplot2` package, and you can further customize the theme with the `theme` function.

Your desired theme looks similar to the `theme_bw()` built in theme. To add this theme, just put a `+ theme_bw()` at the end of the code that generates your plot:

```
code for your plot +
theme_bw()
```

You can customize the theme further. It looks like your desired appearance does not have a border while `theme_bw()` does. You can remove that border with the `theme()` function. You need to call the `theme()` function after you set `theme_bw()` or your customized theme will be replaced with `theme_bw()` presets.

```
code for your plot +
theme_bw() +
theme(panel.border = element_blank())
```

Comment: Thank you, I will try it. But I already added the "theme_minimal" to the end of my code. As I explained, when I run the single plots everything works fine but as soon as I try to combine them the problem with the other background occurs. It's a bit annoying since the rest of my plots has the proper background.

Comment: @Jessi - What code are you using to combine them? Something there could be overriding your theme. Wait and apply your theme at the very end.